# Pivot with multiple colums and rows

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

Could you help me to achieve the following

I have this SQL output table

```
DateWeek Keep_1 This_1 Order_1 Keep_2 This_2 Order_2 Keep_1-Keep_2 This_1-This_2 Order_1-Order_2
1/1/2013 9      8      7       6       5     4       3             3             3
```

and turn it into

```
RowOrder Column_1 Column_2 Column_1-Column_2
Keep     9        6        3
This     8        5        3
Order    7        4        3
```

As you see I have to keep the order in the rows, so I can not order alphabetically. Also I have to stack the `Keep_1 This_1 Order_1` together and `Keep_2 This_2 Order_2` also together and operate `Column_1` with `Column_2`

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES`:

```
select c.roworder,
  c.col1,
  c.col2,
  c.col3
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('Keep', Keep_1, Keep_2, Keep_1_Keep_2),
    ('This', This_1, This_2, This_1_This_2),
    ('Order', Order_1, Order_2, Order_1_Order_2)
) c (roworder, col1, col2, col3)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36569/5).

This can also be done using a `UNION ALL` query in any database:

```
select 'Keep' RowOrder, 
  Keep_1 col1, 
  Keep_2 col2, 
  Keep_1_Keep_2 col3
from yourtable
union all
select 'This' RowOrder, 
  This_1 col1, 
  This_2 col2, 
  This_1_This_2 col3
from yourtable
union all
select 'Order' RowOrder, 
  Order_1 col1, 
  Order_2 col2, 
  Order_1_Order_2 col3
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36569/7)